# Ubuntu - no gear for Wayland / X11

Tags: xorg, wayland

The gear for choosing X11 / Wayland on login screen is absent. X11 starts silently.

Made a new user and the gear was present for the new user (only for him). After reboot again silently starts X11 and no option to choose. For old and new user.

```
~$ grep -i WaylandEnable /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
WaylandEnable=true
```

What's wrong with this system?

Comment: Just to be clear, the login screen shows up but the gear is missing from the login screen or does it bypass the login and automatically login after boot? Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hello. You are telling us about the DE but not about the version of Ubuntu being used.

Comment: Also what hardware(video card) does your machine have?  Nvidia hardware will typically suppress the Wayland option these days (any current release).  Some older releases did allow for Wayland by switching off Nvidia and using Intel, but that feature got dropped.

Comment: Just upgraded 21.04 -> 21.10 -> 22.04 RC. Dunno, if it was the same for older versions.

Comment: Login screen shows up, all is fine. Besides the gear for choosing session does not appears.

Comment: AMD® A6-5400k apu with radeon(tm) hd graphics × 2

Comment: BTW I manually disabled wayland via WaylandEnable=false

Then I re-enabled it to:
WaylandEnable=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same thing is happening to me after a recent update to 22.04. Wayland worked fine until yesterday.
I submitted a bug report about it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1969254

Comment: same here, on both upgrade and fresh install from daily image. A bit scary that this happeneing just a few days before the release. The parent bug report is marked Critical and is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1969243

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

1. Enable unreleased updates
   [ Alberto Milone ]

   - Default to Wayland for hybrid systems with Nvidia graphics drivers.
   - Default to Xorg but offer Wayland with the gear button on the login screen for non-hybrid systems with Nvidia graphics drivers. (LP: #1968929)
2. Workaround
   Create a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-power-management.conf` containing the text:

   ```
   options nvidia NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations=1
   ```

Otherwise, follow these bug reports:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1969243
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1968929
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1876632

Comment: fixed by updates